# Что за библиотеки используются для функций (initgr, move, draw, endgr) и где их можно взять?

Tags: c

Читаю книжку по машинной графике (картинки там больно красивые, и примеры интересные)

Аммерал Л. Принципы программирования в машинной графике (1992)

Но вот в первом же примере не могу понять что за библиотеки используются для функций(initgr, move, draw, endgr) и где их можно взять...

Сам пример:

```
#include ? // вот тут то и вопрос.

main()

{

    float xA, yA, xB, yB, xC, yC, xD, yD,
        xxA, yyA, xxB, yyB, xxC, yyC, xxD, yyD, p, q;
    int i;
    p=0.95; q=1.0-p;
    xA=2.0; xB=8.0;xC=8.0; xD=2.0;
    yA=0.5;yB=0.5;yC=6.5;yD=6.5;
    initgr();
    for(i=0;i<50;i++)
    {
        move(xA,yA);
        draw(xB,yB); draw(xC,yC); draw(xD,yD);draw(xA,yA);
        xxA=p*xA+q*xB; yyA=p*yA+q*yB; xxB=p*xB+q*xC; yyB=p*yB+q*yC;
        xxC=p*xC+q*xD; yyC=p*yC+q*yD; xxD=p*xD+q*xA; yyD=p*yD+q*yA;
        xA=xxA; xB=xxB; xC==xxC; xD=xxD;
        yA=yyA; yB=yyB; yC=yyC; yD=yyD;
    }   
    endgr();
}
```

использую sublime + mingw.

Comment: учитывая, что книге аж 23 года, это могут быть какие-нибудь совершенно неизвестные нынче билиотеки

Comment: @Amelkai Смотрю в книгу, вижу (красивую) фигу!:) Я думаю, что в книге должно указываться, что откуда берется.:)

Comment: Вы не [это](http://www.opita.net/node/570?page=2) искали?

Comment: @Amelkai #include ? // вот тут то и вопрос: Быть или не быть.

Comment: Может, попробуете вместо этого [Processing](https://processing.org/)? На нём очень [красивые штуки](https://processing.org/exhibition/) рисуют, много литературы. Принципы те же, но язык Java-подобный.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрел в книгу и адаптировал свой старый код. Вот необходимые два файла

newgraf.h

```
#ifndef __NEWGRAF_H_
#define __NEWGRAF_H_

void initgr();
void move(float x, float y);
void draw(float x, float y);
void endgr();

extern float curr_x;
extern float curr_y;

#endif
```

newgraf.c

```
#include "newgraf.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

float curr_x;
float curr_y;

int width;
int height;

char * buff; // buffer for image
int coeff = 100; // coeff to multiply x and y
int bpp = 3; // bytes per pixel

void pixel(float x, float y) {
    int coor = (y * width + x) * bpp;
    switch (bpp) {
        case 1:
            buff[coor] = 0x0;
            break;
        case 3:
            buff[coor] = 0x0;
            buff[coor+1] = 0x0;
            buff[coor+2] = 0x0;
            break;
        case 4:
            buff[coor] = 0x0;
            buff[coor+1] = 0x0;
            buff[coor+2] = 0x0;
            buff[coor+3] = 0x0;
            break;  
        default:
            break;
    }
}

void initgr() {
    curr_x = 0;
    curr_y = 0;
    width = 9*coeff;
    height = 7*coeff;
    int size = width*height*bpp;
    buff = (char*) malloc(size);
    memset(buff, 0xFF, size);
}

void move(float x, float y) {
    curr_x = x; //было curr_y = x
    curr_y = y;

}

#define roundf(x) floor(x + 0.5f)

#define max(a,b) \
   ({ __typeof__ (a) _a = (a); \
       __typeof__ (b) _b = (b); \
     _a > _b ? _a : _b; })

void draw(float x, float y) {
    // http://compgraphics.info/2D/DDA_line.php , немного адаптированно
    // (1) Целочисленные значения координат начала и конца отрезка, 
    // округленные до ближайшего целого
    int iX1 = roundf(x*coeff);
    int iY1 = roundf(y*coeff);
    int iX2 = roundf(curr_x*coeff);
    int iY2 = roundf(curr_y*coeff);

    // (2) Длина и высота линии
    int deltaX = abs(iX1 - iX2);
    int deltaY = abs(iY1 - iY2);

    // (3) Считаем минимальное количество итераций, необходимое
    // для отрисовки отрезка. Выбирая максимум из длины и высоты
    // линии, обеспечиваем связность линии
    int length = max(deltaX, deltaY);
// особый случай, на экране закрашивается ровно один пиксел
    if (length == 0)
    {
        pixel(iX1, iY1);
        return;
    }

      // (4) Вычисляем приращения на каждом шаге по осям абсцисс и ординат
      double dX = (x - curr_x) * coeff / length;
      double dY = (y - curr_y) * coeff / length;

      // (5) Начальные значения
      double xx = curr_x * coeff;
      double yy = curr_y * coeff;

      // Основной цикл
      length++;
      while (length--)
      {
            xx += dX;
            yy += dY;
            pixel(roundf(xx), roundf(yy));
      }

    curr_x = x;
    curr_y = y;
}

void endgr() {
    FILE *f;
    int i;
    unsigned char file[14] = {
        'B','M', // magic
        0,0,0,0, // size in bytes
        0,0, // app data
        0,0, // app data
        40+14,0,0,0 // start of data offset
    };
    unsigned char info[40] = {
        40,0,0,0, // info hd size
        0,0,0,0, // width
        0,0,0,0, // heigth
        1,0, // number color planes
        24,0, // bits per pixel
        0,0,0,0, // compression is none
        0,0,0,0, // image bits size
        0x13,0x0B,0,0, // horz resoluition in pixel / m
        0x13,0x0B,0,0, // vert resolutions (0x03C3 = 96 dpi, 0x0B13 = 72 dpi)
        0,0,0,0, // #colors in pallete
        0,0,0,0, // #important colors
        };

    int w=width;
    int h=height;

    int padSize  = (4-(w*bpp)%4)%4;
    int sizeData = w*h*bpp + h*padSize;
    int sizeAll  = sizeData + sizeof(file) + sizeof(info);

    file[ 2] = (unsigned char)( sizeAll    );
    file[ 3] = (unsigned char)( sizeAll>> 8);
    file[ 4] = (unsigned char)( sizeAll>>16);
    file[ 5] = (unsigned char)( sizeAll>>24);

    info[ 4] = (unsigned char)( w   );
    info[ 5] = (unsigned char)( w>> 8);
    info[ 6] = (unsigned char)( w>>16);
    info[ 7] = (unsigned char)( w>>24);

    info[ 8] = (unsigned char)( h    );
    info[ 9] = (unsigned char)( h>> 8);
    info[10] = (unsigned char)( h>>16);
    info[11] = (unsigned char)( h>>24);

    info[20] = (unsigned char)( sizeData    );
    info[21] = (unsigned char)( sizeData>> 8);
    info[22] = (unsigned char)( sizeData>>16);
    info[23] = (unsigned char)( sizeData>>24);

    f = fopen("img.bmp","wb");
    fwrite(file,1,sizeof(file),f);
    fwrite(info,1,sizeof(info),f);


    unsigned char bmppad[3] = {0,0,0};

    for(i=0; i<h; i++)
    {
        fwrite(buff+(w*(h-i-1)*bpp),bpp,w,f);
        fwrite(bmppad,1,(4-(w*bpp)%4)%4,f);
    }
    fclose(f);

    free(buff);
}
```

код жутковат, но писано давно и на коленке. Но самое главное - оно рабочее и достаточно платформенно независимо. На выходе выдает bmp файл, который можно открыть любым просмотрщиком картинок. У автора в книге написано, что его картинки размером 7 на 9, но мой код генерирует 700 на 900, домножая координаты на 100 (что бы было приятно смотреть).

Как использовать. Скопируйте указанные файлы в нужную папку, создайте файл с `main.c`, в который добавьте свой код (или с книги). В include добавьте `#include "newgraf.h"`. Компилировать так `gcc main.c newgraf.c -lm`.

**Bonus:**

Картинка, которую нагенерировал код, немного отличается от того, что указанно у автора. Я не сверял дословно main.c, но думаю, что там есть ошибка. Для проверки я написал ещё и генератор в svg, и он выдал ту же картинку.

newgraf_svg.c

```
#include "newgraf.h"
#include <stdio.h>

float curr_x;
float curr_y;

int width;
int height;

int coeff = 100;
FILE * f;

void initgr() {
    curr_x = 0;
    curr_y = 0;
    width = 9*coeff;
    height = 7*coeff;
    f = fopen("img.svg", "w");
    fprintf(f, "<svg height=\"%d\" width=\"%d\">\n", height, width);
}

void move(float x, float y) {
    curr_x = x;
    curr_y = y;
}

void draw(float x, float y) {
    fprintf(f, "<line x1=\"%f\" y1=\"%f\" x2=\"%f\" y2=\"%f\" style=\"stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:1\" />\n", curr_x*100, curr_y*100, x*100, y*100);
    curr_x = x;
    curr_y = y;
}

void endgr() {
    fprintf(f, "</svg>\n");

    fclose(f);
}
```

для компиляции не нужно менять код, просто использовать другой си файл `gcc main.c newgraf_svg.c`.

Comment: Могу предположить, что ошибка из книги может быть тут в двойном равно: xA=xxA; xB=xxB; **xC==xxC**; xD=xxD;

Comment: подтверждаю. Исправил и теперь картинка соответствует заявленной.

Answer (score 4):

Цитата из книги:

> Здесь объясняется, как программисты могут использовать плоттеры и
>   другие графические устройства, без анализа подробностей их работы и
>   без учета конкретных особенностей доступных устройств. Надеюсь, что
>   читатель одобрит подобный приборно-независимый подход. В любом случае
>   так можно избежать недоразумений, которые могут появиться при изучении
>   конкретных программ и аппаратных реализаций.

Пояснение: вы сами выбираете, какую графическую систему использовать, главное что бы она имела описанные возможности: начать, переместить перо, нарисовать линию, закончить.